# URL cannot be null

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on an Spring-boot application in which hibernate is being used for MySQL database to connect.

Below is the code in my application.yml file and aplication.properties file :

Application.yml :

```html
  datasource:
   
     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digital
     username: <username>
     password: <password>
     driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Application.properties file :

```html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digital
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But when i am running the application, its giving an error saying URL cannot be null.

Trace trace :

```html
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) [spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) [spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53230b11.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]

2019-06-21 16:03:12.213  WARN 20072 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53230b11.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80c6ca9c.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:308) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
 ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why you use both a yaml file and a property file?

Comment: just got some of the answer at Stackoverflow itself so giving try...initially i used only yml file but was getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

i think in your yml file is the Header spring missing:

```
spring:
    datasource:

         url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digital
         username: <username>
         password: <password>
         driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```